# convert small long to big Long in java

Tags: java

`long myvariable;` can't have value `null` but `Long myBigVariable;` can, so I want to convert/cast myvariable to big Long so I can assign it value of null. How can I do that?

I tried `myvariable = new Long(null);` and `myvariable = (Long)(null);` they both failed, is there another solution to this ?

**I can't change myvariable to type Long, it has to stay long.**

Comment: Why can't you use Long instead of long?  If you explain what you're trying to do then you'll get better answers.  The problem might not be what you think it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to create a null Long:

```
Long myvariable = null;
```

**EDIT: I can't change myvariable to type Long, it has to stay long.**

Then no, you cannot set a primitive to null.

Answer (score 4):

The primitive type `long` has a default value of `0` (`0L` to be precise) even if you don't assign it anything if it is a field. If it is a local variable you should initialize it explicitly. So you can't have a `null` value for it.

If you want to have some value that is considered "invalid" or "non-existent", but you don't want it to be 0, you can use:

- -1
- `Long.MAX_VALUE` / `Long.MIN_VALUE` (or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

And then have:

```
Long myBigVariable = myvariable == Long.MAX_VALUE 
       ? null 
       : myvariable; // autoboxing here; altarnatively new Long(myvariable)
```

Comment: can I convert it/box/cast or whatever to big Long so I can assign the null value ?

Answer (score 2):

long is a primitive 64 bit integer. Every combination of 64 bits is used to represent a value. There is no way to represent null using long.

Long is a class that represents a 64 bit integer. You can create a Long instance to represent any of the values that long can; or use a null instance to represent null.

```
Long myLongValue = 9223372036854775807L; // OK
Long myLongNull = null; // OK
long myvariable = null; // Error
```

Comment: how can u assign null to primitive ?

Comment: @org.life.java you cannot assign null to a primitive. Period.

Comment: @Joeri :) @Richj Your previous answer before edit was not clear .reverted back my downvote already

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. The long value must be valuated.

Each **object** (including Long) can be null, but no primitive type (int, long, etc.) can. For that reason, a null Long object can't be cast to its primitive type.

When a Long object is cast into a long, the "*longValue()*" method is called to perform the cast. This method can't be called on a null object: it would result in a nullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't change myvariable to type
>   Long, it has to stay long.

Then you can't assign `null` to that variable. There is no way of assigning `null` to a primitive variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried `myvariable = new Long(null);`

Well.. this works for me! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

myvariable = new Long(null); can be complied , but in running time ,it will throws NumberFormatException

Answer (score -1):

Depends which version of Java you are using. Autoboxing is supported since Java 1.5 (or 1.4). This means, that a variable of type long will be automatically converted to Long if this needs to be done.

Comment: Yes, but this conversion will fail if Long object is null

Comment: True, but his conversion is from long to Long, as he wishes to asign null to a long variable, it should be converted to a Long object variable. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: there's obviously no use in converting it and then assigning null. Why would you convert it if you're not interested in the value? Just make a Long with the value null.